# Parsing CSV files with Python IF specific data exists

Tags: python, csv

The data files look like this:

```
"2015","21","2","RICK","D","w","1","1","f","8","","00","","","","","S"
"2015","56","5","RICK","E","g","1","1","k","8","","15","","","","","F"
```

I need to add the third field to total only IF the last field is "S". Otherwise, the line is just skipped.

I tried importing CSV and using the following:

```
for line in csv.reader(file, quotechar='"', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
if line[16] == "S":
    total = total + line[2]
```

This tells me "IndexError: list index out of range". Maybe there is a better way. I thought Import CSV would do most the work for me. What's the best way? At this point, I would take any way that works.

Printing a line displays the following:

```
['"2015"', '"43"', '"2"', '"ZETA"', '"W"', '"x"', '"1"', '"1"', '"d"', '"2"', '""', '"31"', '""', '""', '""', '""', '"N"']
```

Comment: try printing `line` and see what you get

Comment: Is it possible that the file has a final (empty) line with no fields?  Perhaps:  `if line and line[16] == 'S': ...`

Comment: I added a printed line. Thanks.

Comment: I find it interesting that your `reader` object is preserving quotes in the data.  I thought `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` is a directive to `csv.writer` objects and was ignored by `csv.reader` objects. Something is fishy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the file does not consistently have 17 columns.  One way for this to happen would be if there is an extra newline at the end of the file.

Here's how to detect which line causes the problem.

```
reader = csv.reader(file, quotechar='"', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)
for line_num, line in enumerate(reader, start=1):
    try:
        if line[16] == "S":
            total = total + line[2]
    except IndexError:
        # show offending line
        print(line_num, line)
        # reraise to halt execution
        raise
```

Comment: line[2] is string, you have to convert it to integer before sum them up

Comment: @haifzhan:  Fair enough, but that's not the bug in question.

Comment: Sure enough. haifzhan wrote good code, but I somehow added an extra line with 2 spaces in the middle of the 150,000 lines of my CSV file. Your code found the error, which I have added to the start of the program, so a bad line will never cause this problem again. THANK YOU BOTH!!!

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) can do this easily:

```
In [52]:
# read the csv into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\sample.txt', quotechar="\"", header=None)
df
Out[52]:
     0   1   2     3  4  5   6   7  8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15 16
0  2015  21   2  RICK  D  w   1   1  f   8 NaN   0 NaN NaN NaN NaN  S
1  2015  56   5  RICK  E  g   1   1  k   8 NaN  15 NaN NaN NaN NaN  F
In [55]:
# we can filter the values and then call count()
df.loc[df[16] == 'S',16].count()
Out[55]:
1
In [56]:
# we can also show the count for all unique values
df[16].value_counts()
Out[56]:
S    1
F    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

`=`Assigns values from right side operands to left side operand

`if line[16] = "S":`  should be `if line[16] == "S":`

```
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ cat sample.csv 
"2015","21","2","RICK","D","w","1","1","f","8","","00","","","","","S"
"2015","56","5","RICK","E","g","1","1","k","8","","15","","","","","F"
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ cat test.py 
import csv
with open("sample.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    total = 0
    for line in csvreader:
        if line[16] =="S":
            total = total + int(line[2])

    print "total is:{}".format(total)
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ python test.py 
total is:2
```

Based on your code:

```
import csv
file = open("sample.csv")
total = 0
for line in csv.reader(file, quotechar='"', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
    if line[16] == "S":
        total = total + int(line[2])

file.close()
print "total:{}".format(total)
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ python test.py 
total:2
```

Please makes sure all your input lines have 17 fields, and converts 3rd column of each before you sum them up.

to check which lines do not have 17 fields.
    if len(line) != 17:
        print line

Comment: That would be a `SyntaxError`.  My guess is that the OP's original code doesn't have that error.

Comment: Correct Steven, my typo here. Sorry. Nice catch though haifzhan!

Comment: I tried your code 100%. I still get:     if line[16] == "S":
IndexError: list index out of range. If you print line, does it look like mine?

Comment: you might have 1) empty lines  2) lines contains more than or less than 17 columns. the code works if the input is the 2 lines you provided in the question

Answer (score -1):

You might consider using negative array indices to access items from the ends of arrays:

```
total = 0
for line in cvs.reader(...):
    if line[-1] == "S":
        total += int(line[2])
```

Comment: "The root cause of your problem is assuming that line has been split on white space."  On what basis do you make that claim?  I don't see it.

Comment: I see, yes, I hurried to get the answer out. I'll rephrase that.

Comment: Dang, it get's worse. My answer was based on my bug.  My suggestion for negative indices stands though :)  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Using negative indices in this context may mask bugs in the data.  A line with only 4 fields would pass silently.

Comment: Very true; adding or subtracting  columns is an excellent way to expose the fragility of parsing non-self-descriptive data.  In my own experience data is more likely to grow a column than shrink one, thank you for sharing your experience.